Serilog doesn't work in BackgroundService
We have a .NET 6.0 Console Application that we want to run as a Windows Service, it works but it doesn't log. If I start it with Visual Studio or the EXE directly it works. I found some examples on how to configure Serilog but so far nothing has worked.
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            })
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<WindowsBackgroundService>();
                services.AddConnectionManagement();
                services.AddSessionManagement();
                services.AddTransient<IBLControllerFactory, BLControllerFactory>();
                services.AddTransient<LoginHandler>();
                services.AddHttpClient("123", (serviceProvider, client) =>
                {
                    var config = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();

                    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Origin", config.GetSection("123").GetValue<string>("OriginHeader"));
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(config.GetSection("123").GetValue<string>("ApiBaseAddress"));
                }).AddHttpMessageHandler<LoginHandler>();
            })
            .UseWindowsService(lifetimeConfig =>
            {
                lifetimeConfig.ServiceName = "MES Server";
            });

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.File("logs/log.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, rollOnFileSizeLimit: true)
            .CreateLogger();

        var host = builder.Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}



public sealed class WindowsBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<WindowsBackgroundService> _logger;
    
    public WindowsBackgroundService(ILogger<WindowsBackgroundService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Log.Information("Start service");
    }
}


What if you provide an absolute path (such as C:\temp\log.txt) instead of a relative path? Do you see logs then?

Why is WindowsBackgroundService mixing calls to Serilog with a constructor injected logger from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging? Use one or the other, not both.

There's nothing wrong with Serilog. The working directory of services is System32 unless a different one was specified when the service was created. Either use an absolute path or specify the working directory when registering the service

BTW configuration.AddJsonFile isn't needed, Host.CreateDefaultBuilder adds it by default. The best option is to load the log location from configuration. Services aren't independent applications. They're started and controlled by Service Control Manager, and have the same working folder.

logs/log.txt is a relative path that will resolve to a directory that your service won't likely have permission to access.
Specifying an absolute path is the way to go. Windows service deployment can be a bit tedious - creating the target directory and ensuring your service user account has permission to access it will need to be part of the deployment process.
